# Cannot remove favicon on browser tab

Tags: html

I'm using:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Images/favicon.ico" />
```

to add a small icon to the browser tab, but now I cannot remove it from the browser. I removed it from the `head` section but it's not working. I also cleared the cache, cookies and sessions but still the same. The `.ico` icon is still in the browser tab.

Comment: Which browser?  I believe different browsers cache this icon differently.

Comment: Google Chrome. On other browsers it's removed. Thanks.

Comment: Google Chrome is still seeing the favicon in your project folder. Remove this icon or move it to a different folder. After that delete cache and cookies and you should be all set!

Answer (score 2):

By default, your browser will use the favicon in the same folder with your html file, so removing your link tag will do nothing. You need to move the favicon elsewhere or delete it. Then, if it stills shows up, clear your cache and go to the icon to see the new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is common problem and we need follow 3 steps to remove `.ico` from browser tab.

1. Remove reference from `head` tag where added the icon.
2. Delete or move somewhere else from current folder from where was added.
3. Clear the browser cache, cookie etc.
4. Open the same link in new tab or new browser's